# Computer vision library for Haskell

Tags: haskell, computer-vision

I'm looking for computer vision library (or just a wrapper for library) for Haskell.

I've tried [CV](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/CV), but it fails to compilate because of undefined reference to `cvExtractMSER' (OpenCV version is 2.4.0 and cvExtractMSER was [removed](http://upstream-tracker.org/compat_reports/opencv/2.3.1_to_2.4.0/abi_compat_report.html) in this version).

So are there any alternatives?

Comment: Well, you could just leave a [ticket](https://github.com/aleator/CV/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open) and we could fix that for you. It is most likely not a big deal to repair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [HOpenCV](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HOpenCV) or [CV](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/CV) is your best bet; perhaps you can patch the library to support OpenCV 2.4?
- Other bindings to OpenCV: e.g. [easyVision](https://github.com/albertoruiz/easyVision)

Comment: HOpenCV is meant for opencv 2.0, so it is bit unlikely to work. Is there a particular reason why you would recommend this over CV?

Comment: @aleator I didn't actually notice that we had two different bindings! Updated.

Comment: I have a fork of [HOpenCV](https://github.com/acowley/HOpenCV) that supports OpenCV up through 2.3.1. I haven't gotten around to 2.4 yet. As with all other such wrappers, it is very partial and was developed for personal projects so the part of OpenCV you want might not be covered.