# C or Haskell library to find a form in a bmp file

Tags: c, haskell, bmp, pattern-recognition

We are building a robot and we'd like to give him eyes to be able to avoid bumping into another moving robot. I've already a program that uses a webcam to take photos which are stored in a .bmp file.
We intend to put a flashy red sphere on top of the other robot and what I'd like is to write a program that, given the just-taken .bmp photo, analyzes it, try to find the red sphere, and compute its size, to eventually guess its distance.
What library can I use to find the sphere in a .bmp file?

Comment: For Haskell CV libraries, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10880817/1026598

Comment: yep, I alreayd read that post. It is just that the Haskell HopenCV bindings seems too small at the moment. I am using opencv C library for now, and hopefully I'll manage to get things done. Any reference for image processing would be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 2):

Look at OpenCV (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

This C library provides features for image/form detection and analysis.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll read that. I had previously thought about openCV for getting the image from my webcam, did not think it could do image processing as well.

Comment: You might also be interested in [HOpenCV](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HOpenCV), however it looks as if the current version does not build.

Comment: There are other bindings to OpenCV in Haskell, such as the CV library.  Also, just because something doesn't build on Hackage doesn't mean the package is broken - Hackage isn't really a good build bot (ex: no attempt is made to ensure the proper C developer libraries are installed).

Comment: I had heard of HopenCV, but it seems rather minimal: I can manage to grab images from the webcam, but can't seem to use image processing.